# Parse a DatagramPacket after converting it to a byte array in Java

Tags: java, parsing, udp, arrays

I am trying to parse a DatagramPacket that I will receive at a socket. I know the format of the packet I will receive, which is a DHCPREQUEST packet, but I don't think that really matters. For simplicity's sake, let's just consider the first six fields:

First field is the "opcode", which is 1 byte.
Second field is the "hardware type" which is 1 byte.
Third, "hardware address length", 1 byte.
Fourth, "hops", 1 byte.
Fifth, "transaction identifier xid", 4 bytes.
Sixth, "seconds", 2 bytes.

After I receive the packet, my approach is to convert it to a byte array.

```
DatagramPacket request = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1024], 1024);
socket.receive(request);
byte[] buf = request.getData();
```

At this point, the packet is stored in the byte array `buf` as a series of bytes. Since I know what the structure of this byte sequence is, how can I parse it? The one-byte fields are simple enough, but how about the multiple-bit fields? For example, how can I extract bytes 4 to 7, and store them in a variable named `xid`?

I could manually put each byte into an array:

```
byte[] xid = new byte[4];
xid[0] = buf[4];
xid[1] = buf[5];
xid[2] = buf[6];
xid[3] = buf[7];
```

But that's just tedious, and impractical for fields that are hundreds of bytes in length. The String class can parse substrings given an offset and length; is there a similar method for byte arrays in Java?

Or am I somehow making things difficult for myself?

Comment: Why don't you use TCP/IP instead of UDP? It allows much better mechanisms for use...

Comment: @Thihara: DHCP uses UDP as its transport protocol. I decided to use UDP to emulate the behavior of an actual DHCP server.

Comment: Although I don't know why DHCP doesn't use TCP which seems to be a much more reliable protocol. But what do I know... lol.

Comment: @Terribad - it is because DHCP is a lightweight protocol that doesn't require reliable byte-stream semantics and all of the network packet and local resource overheads that that entails.  (Take a look at the TCP spec, and count the network packets needed to start up and close down a connection.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way to do something like this is probably to use the utility method [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: Thanks, I don't think there is a cleaner way, short of rolling a custom helper method like @Stephen C suggested above.

Comment: You might need to combine this with some helper methods similar to that if you have a byte array and need something other than bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap the byte array in a ByteArrayOutputStream; wrap a DataInputStream around that; then use the methods of DataInputStream.

Comment: I was thinking the same. could you give me a small example of that?

Comment: @Anand I would expect you to be able to code directly from this description

Answer (score 2):

What you do is write yourself some helper methods to extract 2 byte, 4 byte, etc values from the packet, reading the bytes and assembling them into Java `short`, `int` or whatever values.

For example

```
    public short getShort(byte[] buffer, int offset) {
        return (short) ((buffer[offset] << 8) | buffer[offset + 1]);
    }
```

Then you use these helper methods as often as you need to.  (If you want to be fancy, you could have the methods update an attribute that holds the current position, so that you don't have to pass an `offset` argument.)

---

Alternatively, if you were not worried by the overheads, you could wrap the byte array in `ByteArrayInputStream` and a `DataInputStream`, and use the latter's API to read bytes, shorts, ints, and so on.  IIRC, `DataInputStream` assumes that numbers are represented in the stream in "network byte order" ... which is almost certainly what the DHCP spec mandates.

Comment: Could you please explain the logic behind your function? I see, in a mechanical way, that you are left-shifting the byte by 8 bits and OR'ing (adding?) it with the byte in the next array index, but I don't grasp the significance of this operation.

Comment: It is assembling a `short` from a pair of bytes in a very straight-forward weay.  Get a pencil and paper, write the numbers in binary and "hand execute" the code if you don't understand it.

Comment: So I did that and this is what I understand: The function takes the byte at `[offset]` and left-shifts it by 8 bits. Since the byte is 8 bits in size, and left-shifting is not circular, `buffer[offset] << 8` will produce `00000000` regardless of the contents of `buffer[offset]`. Then you OR this `00000000` with `buffer[offset+1]`, which always yields `buffer[offset+1]`... ?

Comment: I understand it now. I wasn't aware that bit-shifting operations in Java always return an int, regardless of the type of operand. So I thought that left-shifting, for example, `0000 0101` by 8 bits would return `0000 0000`, when in reality it would return `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0101 0000 0000`

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to this, but there's a ByteBuffer class:

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(request.getData());

byte opcode = b.get();
byte hwtype = b.get();
byte hw_addr_len = b.get();
byte hops = b.get();
int xid = b.getInt();
short seconds = b.getShort();
```

Or, if you only need a single field:

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.wrap(request.getData());
int xid = b.getInt(4);
```