# Java How to parse raw data from a UDP packet

Tags: java, udp

I have hypothetical data coming from a UDP connection that is in binary form.

Its composed of 5 fields, with a size of 25 bits

their offsets as follows

```
 1. 0-4 ID
 2. 5-10 payload
 3. 11-12 status
 4. 13-23 location
 5. 23-25 checksum
```

**How do I read in this data?**

```
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(18000);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

        while (true)
        {
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

           //not sure how I should be reading the raw binary data back in

        }
```

**How would I store off this data?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774091/parse-a-datagrampacket-after-converting-it-to-a-byte-array-in-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DatagramPacket's [getData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/DatagramPacket.html#getData%28%29) returns the payload as a byte[].  You can use [Arrays.copyOfRange](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29) to get the individual fields (I'm assuming you meant **bytes** in your question, not **bits**):

```
while (true) {
    DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
    // get the entire content
    byte telegramContent[] = receivePacket.getData();
    // and slice it up:

    byte ID[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(telegramContent,0,5); 
    byte payload[] = Arrays.copyOfRange(telegramContent,6,11);
    // and so on.
}
```

After this step you'll have your fields as individual byte arrays, probably some postprocessing/reassembly into other types will be necessary.  During this step probably the most annoying thing is that all Java's types are **signed** whereas in many communication protocols unsigned entities are used, so be careful during this step.

Not mentioned in your question but you might need it later on: assembly of messages for transmission.  I like to use [GNU Trove's TByteArrayList](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TByteArrayList.html) for that task as you don't need to worry about reserving a byte[] with the correct length before you start, just copy in bytes or message segements and once you're done call [toArray](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TByteArrayList.html#toArray%28%29) and voilà, your byte[] is ready for transmission.

Comment: You also need to take account of getOffset() and getLength() in the DatagramPacket.

Comment: @EJP not sure about what you mean - `getData()` gets the telegram's payload as an array, `getOffset()` and `getLength()` are important if you go the `ByteArrayInputStream` route - which I didn't in this example

Comment: @fvu Thank you. This was most helpful!

Comment: And how do I can parse a payload to the human-readable string?