# Getting Actual SNMP Trap packet data

Tags: networking, snmp, snmp4j

I am trying to retrieve the Layer 3 packet data for SNMP Traps. I am using snmp4j, but I am not able to find any API out of snmp4j which gives me the Layer 3 packet data. Is there any tweek present to retrive IP Data from SNMP Traps?

Comment: Then you should directly hook to the port in UDP way, and grab the raw bytes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java How to parse raw data from a UDP packet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713699/java-how-to-parse-raw-data-from-a-udp-packet)